# php exec with WGET creating files

Tags: php, laravel, centos, exec, wget

I'm calling exec to run scripts in backgroud using php exec() and wget. But everytime I call this it's creating a file with url parameters in my server. I tried to disable output and tried to store it to a specific file also. Both failed.

here is my code

```
function execInBackground($cmd)
{
    $cmd = escapeshellcmd($cmd);
    exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
}
```

And I'm calling it like below

```
execInBackground('wget -q http://example.com/d/do-processing?process=501&res=201');
```

So now it will create a file named

> do-processing?process=501&res=201

in my server. Can you guys please mention is there anything I missed while doing this.

I want to call that url in background without saving any output. In worst case I need to store the output of each call to a specific file instead of creating multiple files.

```
exec($cmd . " > process.out 2> process.err < /dev/null &");
```

I tried like above code and didn't worked.

Comment: If you just want to hit the URL in the background and don't want to store the output, you can use CURL http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: check CURL document, you can hit the URL and can ignore output to the browser...check other parameters available for CURL

Comment: I don't want to use curl.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333096/php-shell-exec-wget-to-run-not-in-background

Comment: My requirement is different. Please check the code I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use wgets' `-o` or `--output-file` argument like this:

`exec('wget -q -o /dev/null http://example.com/d/do-processing?process=501&res=201 &');`

Then no output file will be created.